# Why picture content not shown in scrollView on avd however scroll bar is shown

Tags: android-studio, android-view, android-scrollview, android-appbarlayout, android-developer-api

i used horizontal scrollview and inside i put a linear layout and then some pictures but on avd i can't see pictures however scrollbar can be seen. Also i can scroll the scrollbar horizontally the only problem is my pictures are not showing.

Below the xml code of inside horizontalScrollbar:

```
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="402dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img3"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="420dp"
            android:layout_height="262dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageVie3"
            android:layout_width="400dp"
            android:layout_height="260dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:contentDescription="@string/img2"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/img1" />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Try `android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"` instead of `tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"`. You can also do it programmatically like so: `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);`.

Comment: better use recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Change the `tools:srcCompat` into `app:srcCompat`

For example

from this:

```
tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic"
```

to this:

```
app:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic"
```

The `tools` line are for preview and in interface builder only.